# Do people earn health when they get a kill in the Scavenger Pop Up Cup in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have noticed that I do a lot of damage to the person (e.g. I shot a player with a grey SMG 5 times for 17 damage each; the guy had no shield), but when they kill me, they have WAY more health than they should.

This only occurs in the Scavenger Pop Up Cup going on right now, and I'm getting confused because I would like to see how close I was to getting the kill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this was mentioned in [the patch notes](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/patch-notes/v6-30) under Events:

> Players gain 50 health when eliminating an opponent.
>   If health is full, players will receive shield.

Other adjustments include lower material capacity and increased harvesting rate.